# React how can I build minify code in react library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build

I have an issue with React Js app; how should I build minified code of my React code.

**Code Structure**

[My Code File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30YJO.png)

I run my react app with `npm start`

What should I do next to build `minified files`.

```
'build/static/js/main.d3cd729d.js'
'build/static/css/main.9b99bc40.css'
```

Does anyone help?

Comment: You need to setup bundler like `webpack` i hope you are already using this. You checkout the webpack docs for building minified bundles

Comment: how you have created the app?
Have you created with `npx create-react-app` or setup with `webpack`?

Comment: what `command` i will run in my react app [@panther](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1009750/panther)

Comment: `npm install -g create-react-app` to create new app [@sonu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5598423/sonu-bamniya)

Comment: https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/two-quick-ways-to-reduce-react-apps-size-in-production-82226605771a - Look at this article from Medium

Comment: thanks i try (@indranil32)[https://stackoverflow.com/users/2231829/indranil32]

Comment: You can also take a look at https://createapp.dev/ , if you are willing to switch to webpack.

Comment: can explain plz? it online tools to build minify file? [@utkarsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3857918/utkarsh-dixit)

Answer (score 1):

If in your package.json file, these two scripts are exist

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    }
```

Then you can use the `npm run build` command to minify your react app code.

Comment: ok let me try `npm run build` [@s-hesam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8740387/s-hesam)